# Closed Cartesian Category in which LEM fails

Tags: logic, category-theory

What is the simplest example of a Cartesian Closed Category in which it can easily be seen that the law of the excluded middle fails? (I assume the usual way of associating provable sequents with morphisms.)

Comment: How do you interpret $\lor$ in a general CCC?

Comment: So in other words, you're looking for a CCC with finite coproducts (including an initial object 0) along with an object $X$ such that $X \sqcup {}^X 0$ is not a final object?

Answer (score 5):

The *simplest* example? That would be the poset/category $0<1<2,$ which is a Heyting algebra, i.e. a Cartesian closed poset. The complement of $1$ is $0,$ so the LEM fails. If you don't like a poset, then $0<1<2$ also arises as the truth values in the topos of sheaves on Sierpinski space, so that topos also lacks LEM.

Comment: The topos of sheaves on Sierpinski space could also be described as the topos of presheaves on the arrow category $d \rightarrow c$.